# How to generate unique ids in C

Tags: c

I am developing an app which requires to generate an id for new users I want to do it with the smallest number of characters that allows me to create 100 billion diferent possible ids so how should I do that and how to avoid giving two users the same it? Should I look if that id exists? Should I use a random id generator or give ids in order like 001 002 and so on?

Comment: A counter, like you mentioned could be a good solution. This is what databases use. Just save the state between sessions.

Comment: "smallest number of characters" depends on the size of your character set - numbers only [0-9]? Alphanumeric [0-9][a-z][A-Z]?  Something else?

Comment: ^^ what @OregonJim says.  Once you have defined your character set, you can count the number of chars and just use a calculator to multiply up until you reach your '100 billion' limit.  The [number of mults]+1 gives the number of chars needed to uniquely identify those users.

Answer (score 3):

This depends entirely on what kind of functionality you expect from this id, do you intend for these id's to correlate with persisted data, such as a database? If this is the case, it might be more prudent to let the database handle the unique ID generation for you. Otherwise, using sequential values such as 1,2,3... etc would probably be ideal. `unsigned long` will keep you covered for the first 2 billion users... If you somehow go beyond that, you can rethink your data storage then.
The question is very broad.